# Display the value of all checked checkboxes from mysql and display it in table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I designed the user registration page. It has one field hobbies. I designed the field with the help of checkbox. If the user selects two or more hobbies, i saved the hobby id in the database. Now i need to display the hobby names which are all selected by the particular user in their profile edit page. I done the below coding, but it displays the checkbox name from the database without selected. The checkbox name which is selected by the user should be checked. But it doesn't do that. Please provied any help.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM hobbies";
$result = mysqli_query($con, "$query");
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $hobbyid=$r["hobby_id"];
    $hobbyname=$r["hobby_name"]; 
    if($hobby==$r[0]){ //Here $hobby is the hobby id which is entered by the user when registration. That hobby id is saved in the db.
        echo "<input type='checkbox' checked name='check_list[]' value='echo $hobbyid;'> $hobbyname";   
    }else{
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='echo $hobbyid;'> $hobbyname";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please print `$r` also change `value='echo $hobbyid;'` to `value='$hobbyid;'`. No need of `echo`.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to compare `$hobby` against `$r[0]` and not `$hobbyid` ?

Comment: Thks i change value='$hobbyid;' Where i need to print $r.

Comment: I can compare by the above code and also, i can compare by $hobby=$hobbyid. But it also doesn't select any checkboxes. So i tried $r[0]

Comment: Well, do a `var_dump($hobby);` if it contains more than one id that's most likely the fault then.

Comment: From where `$hobby` comes ?

Comment: I had inserted the user information in one table. I retrieved the id of hobby and stored in the variable $hobby in this page.

Comment: Thks i replaced. But the same, it doesn't select any checkboxes.

Comment: what is `$hobby` ? where did you declare `$hobby`?

Comment: I had inserted the user information in one table. I retrieved the id of hobby and stored in the variable $hobby in this edit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried below coding and it gives the result which is i wanted.

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM hobbies";
$flag=false;
$result = mysqli_query($con, "$query");

while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$hobbyid = $r["hobby_id"];
$hobbyname = $r["hobby_name"];
$hob_id=explode(',',$hobby);
$size = sizeof($hob_id);
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) 
{ 
  if($hob_id[$i]==$hobbyid) 
  {
    $flag=true;
  } 
}
if($flag==true) 
{
      ?>
  <input  type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value="<?php echo $r['hobby_id']; ?>" checked  > <?php echo $r['hobby_name']; ?> <br>
  <?php
  $flag=false;
} 
else 
{ 
  ?>
  <input  type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value="<?php echo $r['hobby_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $r['hobby_name']; ?> <br>
  <?php
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try again with below code segment. I have modified your code.
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM hobbies";
$result = mysqli_query($con, "$query");

while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $hobbyid = $r["hobby_id"];
    $hobbyname = $r["hobby_name"]; 

    $isChecked = '';
    if($hobby == $r["hobby_id"]) { //Here $hobby is the hobby id which is entered by the user when registration. That hobby id is saved in the db.
        $isChecked = "checked='checked'";
    }

    echo "<input type='checkbox' $isChecked checked name='check_list[]' value='$hobbyid;'/> $hobbyname";   
}
?>
```

Comment: It checked all the options which are all in the database.

Comment: But i need to display only which is checked by the user.

Comment: if $hobby holds the which is selected by a user, above code should be working but it has some others that will not work as you expected.